# xcode uiwebview Create layout dynamic

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview

Sample image:

[image]

How can I build a way like this in xcode?

Comment: so what have you tried so far?

Comment: add 2 webviews to viewcontroller and stay happy

Comment: What do you mean by bottom fixed?
have you placed these webviews in scrollView?

Comment: Http://imgur.com/a/kIA4y

Bottom is empty. I guess I can not set the layout event. :(

Answer (score 0):

I would use stacked view. Watch this nice introduction to creating layouts: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/218/